# Hibernate: Criteria with many-to-many join table?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Consider the following two relations:

```java
@Entity class Foo {
    @Id id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ATag", 
         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id"),
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    Set<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity class Tag {
    @Id Long id;
    String name;
}
```

There is no corresponding entity class for the join table ATag. Now, I want to get all Foo instances with Tag named 'tag1'. Is it possible using only Criteria?

A subquery may be helpful. However, I can't create DetachedCriteria for class ATag.class which doesn't existed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just dealt with this exact issue.  You're thinking in tables, not objects.  Just reference `tags.name` and let Hibernate take care of the rest:

```java
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
crit.createAlias("tags", "tagsAlias");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("tagsAlias.name", someValue);
```

If you watch the SQL Hibernate spits out, you'll see it uses the join table.

Comment: It is important to note about using the property of the object and not the object itself. Hibernate using Restrictions does not just use POJO defined primary key. Here the example uses the attribute name of the object tags. I lost of time trying to set the whole object instead of explicit say which property needs to be checked under the criteria predicate.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use an alias? Can't you simply use `tags.name` instead of `tagsAlias.name`?

Comment: Creating an alias causes the inner join to happen automatically.

Comment: Works fine for one tag, but how to update this criteria to select Foo's which contains Tags named 'tag1' and 'tag2' on example?

Comment: @Escander just create a for loop and inside it add one Restriction at a time

Comment: @imran.razak can you add some pseudo code? If you about: `crit.createAlias("tags", "tagsAlias").add(Restrictions.eq("tagsAlias.name", someValue1).add(Restrictions.eq("tagsAlias.name", someValue2)....` - this not work correctly.

Comment: `crit.createAlias("tags","tagsAlias"); for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){ crit.add(Restrictions.eq("tagsAlias.name",values[i])); }` don't chain the methods. First create the alias and then inside a loop, use criteria's `add()` method

Comment: @imran.razak Are you tested this? This didn't work, returned list is empty