# Hibernate Criteria Many to Many multiple conditions

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My question regarding the criteria for a Many-to-Many is some what a followup for the existing question on stackoverflow.[Criteria for many- to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744941/hibernate-criteria-with-many-to-many-join-table)

In the referenced question the FOO entities are retrieved for a tag name but i have a situation where i need a FOO object which has both the tags associated to it.
For example i need to get a FOO object which has both
Tag1= hibernate
Tag2= spring.
Any suggestions on how to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of restrictions `linked with or is called a disjunction`. A sequence of restrictions `linked with and is called a conjunction`.

In Hibernate, `Criteria Conjunction` works as logical `AND` operator. conjunction() groups the expressions into a single expression. If all conditions are satisfied, it will return true otherwise false.

So here it goes:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.createAlias("tags", "tagsAlias");

Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
conjunction.add(Restrictions.like("tagsAlias.name", "str1"));
conjunction.add(Restrictions.like("tagsAlias.name", "str2"));

criteria.add(conjunction);

List<Foo> companies = criteria.list();
```

Comment: @user68883 is this what you want.??

Comment: Will give it a try but doesn't using Restrictions.in() return me all the Foo objects with the tags either tag1 or tag2 ??  I want only Foo objects which has both tag1 and tag2.

Comment: @user68883 i have edited the answer give a try with both approaches

Comment: First approch results in all the Foo objects with tag1 or tag2 and second approach results in zero objects. I'm specifically talking about many-to-many just in case if u have missed.

Comment: @user68883 answer edited, replaced or with and for first case, does it work now.

Comment: Thanks Ankur for the suggestions, but even this did not return any results.  I'll try to use an inner query with one condition.

Comment: @user68883 try to see the SQL generated when you are firing at server console or logs